# Armadillo arma::Col of type defined by struct

Tags: c++, c++11, armadillo

I'm working on a translation of a program from MATLAB code to C++ and i decided to use the Armadillo C++ library. In my C++ code I defined a struct type with typedef and then declared an `arma::Col<myType>`, but when i try to compile, the compiler gives me a C2118 error due to `ERROR___INCORRECT_OR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE` error in the Armadillo header file "arma_static_check.hpp" referring to the type myType described before, when i use it in the `arma::Col` definition. Does this mean it's not possible to create an `arma::Col` containing elements of a custom type or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [field class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field)
instead of the [Col](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) class.

The field class can store arbitrary user types. The Col class is only for numerical types (the [Armadillo FAQ](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) says *"Armadillo supports matrices with the following element types: float, double, std::complex, std::complex, short, int, long, and unsigned versions of short, int, long"*).